# C++/C Programming practice on passing structures by reference

Tags: c++, structure

I have been writing a program that has a rather large structure that is passed by reference to a few functions. However, there are a few other functions that need access to small pieces of information within the large structure. It's not being edited, just read.

I was thinking of creating a a second structure that just copies the specific pieces of information needed and passing that by reference, rather than passing the entire structure by reference.

What I am wondering is two things:

1. Since I am passing the large structure by reference, there really is no performance impact. Correct?
2. Even if 1) is correct, is it bad practice to be passing around a structure that shouldn't be edited (even though it wouldn't be edited, but still I'm talking about the principle here).

More specifically:

I have a configuration structure that sets up the programs configuration by calling a function and passing the structure by reference. There is some information (process name, command line arguments) that I want to use for informative purposes only. I'm asking if it's bad practice to pass around a structure that wasn't meant for the purpose of what I want to use it for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Since I am passing the large structure by reference, there really is no performance impact. Correct?

Correct.

> 2) Even if 1) is correct, is it bad etiquette to be passing around a structure that shouldn't be edited (even though it wouldn't be edited, but still I'm talking about the principle here).

You could let your function accept a reference to `const` to make sure the function won't alter the state of the corresponding argument.

> I'm asking if it's bad practice to pass around a structure that wasn't meant for the purpose of what I want to use it for.

I'm not sure what you mean by this. The way you write it, this definitely seems to be a bad practice: you shouldn't use something for doing what it wasn't meant for. That means distorting the semantics of an object. However, the rest of your question doesn't seem to imply this.

Rather, it seems like you are concerned with passing a reference to a function because that may allow the function to alter the argument's state; but provided the function takes a reference to `const`, it won't be able to alter the state of its argument. In that case, no it's not a bad practice.

If you are referring to the fact that the function only need to work with *some* of the data members or member functions of your structure, then again that is not necessarily a bad design. It would be silly to require that each function access *every* member of a data structure.

Of course, this is the best I can write without knowing anything concrete about the semantics of the function and the particular data structure.

Comment: If you look at the bottom I posted more specifically about the scenario.

Answer (score 2):

1. Correct.
2. Pass it by `const` reference; you'll get the performance gains of pass-by-reference withoug allowing editing.

By the way, if only a fraction of the "big structure" is required to that function it may be an indicator that such fields store some information "on their own" - i.e. the rest of the "big struct" is not needed to interpret them correctly. In this case, you may consider moving them to a separate `struct`, that will itself be a member of the first "big struct".

Answer (score 0):

As one step further, you can keep such configuration objects in a shared pointer and pass it anywhere you want and so you dont have to worry about ownership of the structure. In this way you ensure that a single original configuration object is shared by the all program components

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, use const.

If you are doing C++, access those small pieces of information with accessor functions.  Then functions that don't need to change the state of your struct will not have to touch any member fields, only member functions.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `const&` if you aren't modifying the data.

However, your point about "should I copy the data to a smaller `struct`" has mostly been glossed over.  The answer is "maybe".

A good reason not to do it is that it is a waste of time -- literally, it costs time to copy stuff around.

A good reason to do it is that it reduces the effective state of your subprocedure.  A subprocedure that doesn't access global variables (and hence global state), and isn't passed any pointers, has a very limited state.  Procedures with limited state are easier to test, often easier to understand, and usually easier to debug.

Often you want to call each function with the absolute least amount of data required for that function to solve the problem it has.  If you avoid passing in a "pointer to everything" (and references are pointers) to every function, you can maintain this rule, and it can often result in code that is easier to maintain.

On the other hand, stripping the data out of the big monolithic state and into small local `struct`s can contain bugs and errors.

One way to avoid this problem entirely is to avoid the big monolithic state object with parameters all mixed together, and if there are some parameters that are bundled together to answer some questions, they should be in their own sub-`struct` to start with.  Now calling the subprocedure is easy -- you pass in the sub-`struct` which already has the parameters bundled.